# Recursively assert number of moves in Tower of Hanoi

Tags: java, recursion, assert, assertion

One of the tasks we were given at Uni was to write a function that recursively prints out the moves for the *Tower of Hanoi* puzzle:

```
public static void move(int number, char start, char help, char end) {
    if (number == 1) {
        print("Move the top disk from " + start + " to " + end);
    } else {
        move(number - 1, start, end, help);
        print("Move the top disk from " + start + " to " + end);
        move(number - 1, help, start, end);
    }
}
```

Now we have to come up with a function that calculates the number of moves for `n` elements and use an assertion to check the validity of our code using this function.

Obviously the function is given by: `f(n) = 2*f(n-1) + 1` for `n > 1` and `f(n) = 1` for `n = 1`. We can solve this recursive equation and get `f(n) = 2^n - 1`.

By adding `static int count = 0;` to the top of the class and incrementing it after every `print` statement, we can get the total number of moves:

```
public static void move(int number, char start, char help, char end) {
    if (number == 1) {
        print("Move the top disk from " + start + " to " + end);
        count++;
    } else {
        move(number - 1, start, end, help);
        print("Move the top disk from " + start + " to " + end);
        count++;
        move(number - 1, help, start, end);
    }
}
```

and then add an assertion after the function call that checks the value of `counter` with the solved form of the recursive equation:

```
move(n, 'A', 'B', 'C');
assert count == Math.pow(2,n) - 1 : "Number of movements isn't correct.";
```

This works fine. However, I was curious to know whether there is a way to use the `assert` inside of the recursive function itself and check the number of moves with the recursive form of the equation - something like `assert count == 2*f(n-1) + 1`. We would probably have to change the use of our `count`, but I don't know how (or if it's possible at all).

*Note: `print()` merely delegates to the standard `System.out.println()`.*

*Edit: I'd prefer solutions that don't require changing the signature of the `move` function (Or somebody saying that this would definitely not be possible without such a change)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to add the count as a parameter to the function

`public static int move(int number, char start, char help, char end, int count)`

the initial call would be something like

```
int count == Math.pow(2,n) - 1
move(n,'A','B','C',count);
```

and then inside the function

```
public static int move(int number, char start, char help, char end,int count){
    if(number == 1){
        print("Move the top disk from " + start + " to " + end);
        assert count == 1; 
        return 1;
    }else{
        int subCount1 = move(number-1,start,end,help, (count-1)/2);
        print("Move the top disk from " + start + " to " + end);
        int subCount2 = move(number-1,help,start,end, (count-1)/2);
        assert count == (subCount1 + subCount2 + 1);
        return count; // it's the same as returning 2*f(n-1)+1;
    }
}
```

The count parameter serves as an expected assertion value.
This is pure intuition and it may require some fine changes. I'm not 100% on the `(count-1)/2` part.

**EDIT** 
If you do not want to alter the method signature try something like this:

```
public static void move(int number, char start, char help, char end) {
    if (number == 1) {
        print("Move the top disk from " + start + " to " + end);
        count++;
    } else {
        int stepsBeforeMove1 = count;
        move(number - 1, start, end, help);
        int stepsAfterMove1 = count;
        print("Move the top disk from " + start + " to " + end);
        count++;
        int stepsBeforeMove2 = count; //this is just for the sake of clarity
        move(number - 1, help, start, end);
        int stepsAfterMove2 = count;
        assert ((stepsAfterMove1-stepsBeforeMove1) + (stepsAfterMove2-stepsBeforeMove1) + 1) == Math.pow(2,number) - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would probably work correctly, however, I'd prefer a method that doesn't require changing the signature of the function :) (This might, however, be the only possibility to make it work)

Answer (score 0):

If you separated your game board from your solver (so `Towers` has a `move` method, and `Solver` has `solve(towers)`), you could decorate the `Towers` to instrument `move`. But you'd have to move away from static methods, and you'd get slightly over-engineered OO code instead of procedural code.

Comment: Yeah, this is just supposed to be one class with a `main` function and the `move` function.